# Check conditions after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Can I use `groupby` and elegantly check if a condition is true (e.g. the group contains a given value) in a single expression?

Currently, I use for

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1', 'A'], ['1', 'A'], ['1', 'B'], ['2', 'B']], columns=['col_1', 'col_2'])
```

`apply()` to get what I want:

```
df.groupby('col_1').col_2.apply(lambda s: 'A' in s.values) # or other conditions
```

But this is neither efficient nor elegant. Other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First compare values of `col_2` for boolean mask and then aggregate [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
s = df.col_2.eq('A').groupby(df['col_1']).any()
print (s)
col_1
1     True
2    False
Name: col_2, dtype: bool
```

Or create helper column `new`:

```
s = df.assign(new = df.col_2.eq('A')).groupby('col_1')['new'].any()
print (s)
col_1
1     True
2    False
Name: new, dtype: bool
```